# No Suitable Constructor Found for Student (no arguments)

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have found code that I thought would help me finish my assignment. However, I am getting the error stated in the title. This is the program. I am very new to Java, so please excuse any mistakes in my formatting. The error highlights "the first bracket in public Course.

```
public class Student //Student Class
{
Address home = new Address("1027 Charleston St","Lincoln", "Ne", 68508);
Address school = new Address("1534 E St", "Lincoln", "Ne", 68508);
Student mike = new Student("Mike", "Vinci", home, school);
Student john = new Student("John", "Doe", home, school, 90, 80, 199);

//Below are the ints used
int test1 = 0;
int test2 = 0;
int test3 = 0;
int avg2;
int error = 0;

public void setTestScore(int testNum, int score)
{
    if (testNum == 1)
        test1 = score;
    else if (testNum == 2)
        test2 = score;
    else if (testNum == 3)
        test3 = score;
}

public int getTestScore(int testNum)
{
    if (testNum == 1)
        return test1;
    else if (testNum == 2)
        return test2;
    else if (testNum == 3)
        return test3;
    else
         return error;
}

public int average(int test1, int test2, int test3)
{
    int avg2 = ((test1 + test2 + test3)/3); //finds the average of the tests
    return avg2;
}

private String firstName, lastName; //private ints for coding
private Address homeAddress, schoolAddress;

public Student (String first, String last, Address home, Address school) 
{
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
    homeAddress = home;
    schoolAddress = school;
}

public Student (String first, String last, Address home, Address school, int test11, int test22, int test33) 
{
    firstName = first;
    lastName = last;
    homeAddress = home;
    schoolAddress = school;
    test11 = test1;
    test22 = test2;
    test33 = test3;
}

public String toString() 
{
    String result;
    result = firstName + " " + lastName + "\n";
    result += "Home Address:\n" + homeAddress + "\n";
    result += "School Address:\n" + schoolAddress + "\n";
    result += "Average=" + avg2 + " with Tests: " + test1 + ", " + test2 + ", " + test3;
    return result; //returns the result
}

class Address
{
private String streetAddress, city, state;
private long zipCode;

public Address(String street, String town, String st, long zip)
{
    streetAddress = street;
    city = town;
    state = st;
    zipCode = zip;
}

 public String toString()
 {
    String result;
    result = streetAddress + "\n";
    result += city + "," + state + " " + zipCode;
    return result; //returns the result
 }
} 
}
 public class Course extends Student //Course class
{
private String course;
private Student s1, s2, s3, s4, s5;
private int studentcount = 1;

public Course (String name)
{
course = name;
} 

public Student addStudent(String first, String last, Address home, Address    school)
{

if (studentcount == 1){
  s1 = new Student(first,last,home,school);
  studentcount++;          
  return s1;
}    

 if (studentcount == 2) {
  s2 = new Student(first,last,home,school);
      studentcount++;
  return s2;

}
else if (studentcount == 3){
  s3 = new Student(first,last,home,school);
  studentcount++;
      return s3;

}
else if (studentcount == 4){
  s4 = new Student(first,last,home,school);
      studentcount++;
  return s4;

}
else if (studentcount == 5) {
  s5 = new Student(first,last,home,school);
      studentcount++;
  return s5;

}
else {
System.out.println("No More students allowed in the class");
return null;
}

}

public double average()
 {
 return (s1.average() + s1.average() + s1.average() + s1.average() +  s1.average()) / 5.0;
}

 public String roll()
{
 String results = "";

if (studentcount == 1){
  results += s1.toString () +"n";
  return results;
}    

 if (studentcount == 2) {
  results += s1.toString () +"n";
  results += s2.toString () +"n";
  return results;

}
else if (studentcount == 3){
  results += s1.toString () +"n";
  results += s2.toString () +"n";
  results += s3.toString () +"n";
  return results;

}
else if (studentcount == 4){
  results += s1.toString () +"n";
  results += s2.toString () +"n";
  results += s3.toString () +"n";
  results += s4.toString () +"n";
  return results;

}
else if (studentcount == 5) {
  results += s1.toString () +"n";
  results += s2.toString () +"n";
  results += s3.toString () +"n";
  results += s4.toString () +"n";
  results += s5.toString () +"n";

  return results;
    } 
    else{
   return null;
}   

}
}
```

Comment: @Trobbins Woops! I will add it.

Comment: Here's a [a fishing pole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) for you, good luck!

Comment: add a default constructor to Student class..

Comment: @TheUnicornMaster A pity you deleted that question about the average. I was ready to answer...

Comment: @laune It was a poor question, but I can put it back up if you wish. Edit: undeleted

Comment: @TheUnicornMaster It is a poor exercise, to begin with. And some of the comments were below par. I'm always in a quandary whether to respond to requests for help with homework. Here I would have.

Comment: @laune it's back up now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Course` class extends `Student` (which doesn't make much sense, but that is beside the point).

The constructor in any class always invokes its superclass constructor. You can do this either explicitly with

```
public Course() {
    super(...);
}
```

in which case you invoke the superclass constructor taking the arguments you specify, or implicitly:

```
public Course() {
    // no explicit call to super(...);
}
```

in which case you implicitly invoke the *superclass constructor taking no arguments*.

In your case, you don't explicitly call `super(...)`, so the compiler is going to implicitly invoke the superclass constructor `Student()`: however, since there is no such constructor (the only constructor in `Student` takes two strings and two `Address`es) you get a compile error.

Comment: thanks! I will accept your answer soon. I used extends because I wasn't sure how to connect the two classes. Sorry for any incorrect terminology.

Comment: Using inheritance means that a `Course` is a `Student`. Which, just by semantics, is clearly not true. It also implies that a course has a first name, a last name, and two addresses. Which also doesn't make much sense...

Answer (score 1):

You are extending the `Student` class in the `Course` class. You need to call the `super()` method explicitly which will match the constructor of the Student class. By default it call the default constructor, which is not available in your case.

You can define the no argument constructor in the Student class and issue will be resolved.

```
public Student() { }
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix that particular error, you need to add a no-arg constructor to Student.

```
public Student(){
    //empty
}
```

You have several other issues that are somewhat concerning, such as Course extending Student, but that's an entirely different discussion.